# Peculiarity of overridden property setter in subclass

Tags: python, properties, overriding

So I have this:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        print 'enter Base init'
        self._set_x(val)
        print 'leave Base init'

    def _get_x(self):
        return self._x

    def _set_x(self, val):
        print 'enter Base _set_x'
        self._x = val
        print 'leave Base _set_x'

    x = property(_get_x, _set_x)

class Child(Parent):

    def _set_x(self, val):
        print 'enter Child _set_x'
        y = val * 2
        super(Child, self)._set_x(y)
        print 'leave Child _set_x'

child = Child(5)
num = child.x
child.x = 5
print num == child.x
```

And when I run it, I get this:

```
enter Base init
enter Child _set_x
enter Base _set_x
leave Base _set_x
leave Child _set_x
leave Base init
enter Base _set_x
leave Base _set_x
False
```

I've been reading around, and people are saying that the overriding shouldn't work, but my question is why is there this seeming inconsistency here?  The subclass' setter gets called when calling from init, but when you later act on the already initialized object, it calls the base's setter.  Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you call it inconsistently — once directly, and once via a property. Change `self._set_x(x)` in `Parent.__init__` to `self.x = x` and you'll see `Child._set_x` is never called. To override a setter in a child class, you can use `property.setter` as decorator:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.x.setter
    def x(self, arg):
        super()._set_x(arg)
```

Or add a level of indirection to the property:

```
class Parent(object):
    # ...
    x = property(
        lambda self:    self._get_x(),
        lambda self, x: self._set_x(x)
    )
```

The overriding doesn't work directly, because property stores concrete method objects (`Parent._get_x` and `Parent._set_x`), and doesn't look them up again, even if the type of the object happens to change — the code that runs is the same regardless. Indirection forces lookup in the dynamic type of `self`, which allows for overriding.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Because even in the scope of the parent's init, it still looks at the full child self for the setter.  I was thinking that the base class' init method would not find the child's setter without extra work, but now that I think about it, of course that makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no inconsistency. The `__init__` method explicitly calls `self._set_x` via attribute lookup. `self` refers to a `Child` object here, and since `Child` defines `_set_x`, and the `Child` class is first in the object's [Method Resolution Order](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) (MRO), its version of `_set_x` is the version that gets called.

But the `x` property is defined inside `Parent`. There's no child involved yet, so the versions of `_set_x` and `_get_x` passed to `property` are the versions defined in `Parent`. Now, when the `x` attribute of the `Child` is accessed, Python first looks for `x` in the `Child` class. But it doesn't find it, because `Child` doesn't define it. Then it goes to the next class in the MRO: `Parent`. It finds the `x` there, and uses it as defined in `Parent`.

Comment: Yeah, you and @Cat Plus Plus got to the same point.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
x = property(_get_x, _set_x)
```

Here `x` becomes a property with getter `Parent._get_x` and setter `Parent._set_x`.

If you add the line `x = property(Parent._get_x, _set_x)` to the `Child` class, the property will be redefined and will work as you expected.

Comment: That just begs the question though.  I edited the question to remove the misdirecting name confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the methods as objects. The property x on your Parent class has been bound to the _get_x/_set_x method objects of the parent class. But in your Child class you are calling that class' own _set_x method object.